# Stepper motor resolution calculation

Tags: stepper-motor, encoder, rotary

I am not familiar on how to calculate the stepper motor resolution to operate with multi-turn absolute rotary encoder.

Stepper motor details as follows,

- Total step - 600;
- speed - 160 pps;
- Motor type - Biploar;
- Step mode - 1/8.

Please advise.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a link to the motor and encoder datasheets. "Valve" is not the right word. If you add your location and language into your user profile we may be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your motor has a total step of 600. It means, for a complete revolution, you have 600 steps. Hence the resolution appears to be 360°/600 = 0.6° per step. This is the resolution in what is called FULL MODE.

However, your motor can works in STEP MODE 1/8. That means that you can move the motor by 1/8 of a step. Hence, you can achieve 8 more steps and thus increase your resolution by 8. In this mode, your actual resolution is 0.6°/8 = 0.075°

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. My encoder lists Linearity Resolution as 1/4096 and am Using CALT Encoder and not sure what it means ?      (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32955320747.html?gps-id=pcStoreJustForYou&scm=1007.23125.137358.0&scm_id=1007.23125.137358.0&scm-url=1007.23125.137358.0&pvid=1f05fdb6-0b18-4d85-83ed-6481aaacc28b&spm=a2g0o.store_home.smartJustForYou_98574137.2)